# Do I need to uninstall 10.04 to upgrade to 12.04?

Tags: upgrade

I currently have Ubuntu 10.04 installed alongside windows 7 and would like to uninstall it so i can use 12.04. Having looked on the net it seems as if it is rather complicated to uninstall without encountering anuy issues.

Does anyone know of an Idiot Proof way of uninstalling without breaking my laptop. Im not that technical when it comes to dealing with Operating systems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have to uninstall 10.04 in order to upgrade it to 12.04.

Firstly, you can upgrade your Ubuntu directly using Upgrade manager (as 10.04 and 12.04 are both LTS (long-term support) releases, there's a direct upgrade path, despite 10.04 not being "Ubuntu minus 1"). This will allow you to keep your installed applications and settings:

- [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04)

If you prefer to do a clean re-install, you will need to prepare a bootable Ubuntu 12.04 CD or flash USB drive, back up all your data, boot from the CD and install 12.04 onto the same partition where 10.04 currently resides. The partition will be formatted in the process leaving no trace of your old OS.

This site is full of detailed recipes how to perform an upgrade or a clean install.

Comment: Thanks very much for the info, doesnt sound as daunting as i first thought

Comment: Just to add on to the question, will i be able to add more hard drive space to my install than previously allocated to 10.04?